# Writing to the program memory of AVR ATmega16 in runtime?

Tags: assembly, avr, atmega

Is it possible to write to the program memory of Atmel's Atmega16 while runtime? I'm trying to write a program to sort a given set of numbers in the program memory and i have to swap the data so i do need to use SPM(Store Program Memory), But i'm not sure i can change the contents of program memory while i'm running the program!
I guess the operation for write must be implemented in somewhere like BOOT SECTION of the program memory but i cant find a way to do this. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: You can, but you don't want to, it's a bad idea. Copy your data into ram, and sort it there.

Answer (score 1):

You can, and especially low-level system modules like boot loaders do (need to) write to program memory.

Note that some of the AVRs allow word-wise write to PM, others will only allow replacing complete flash pages. Obviously, your code needs to ensure it's not currently using that word or page while reprogramming.

Generally, *sorting* numbers in program memory sounds like a bad idea, though. You will exhaust your flash cycles pretty fast, and the main question remains: Why don't you sort before writing to flash?